# Apache Pulsar Open ID authentication: Why do I receive unauthorised when correct client credentials are passed?

Tags: openid-connect, apache-pulsar

I've been attempting to configure Apache Pulsar cluster to enable OpenID Connect authentication by following the documentation/SO answers. However I receive the following unauthorized error...

```
[main] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.WorkerUtils - Create Pulsar Admin to service url http://10.110.124.172:8080: authPlugin = org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.auth.oauth2.AuthenticationOAuth2, authParams = {"privateKey":"file:///credentials/credentials_file.json","audience":"https://auth0.someweb.com/api/v2/","issuerUrl":"https://login.someweb.com/"}, tlsTrustCerts = null, 
allowTlsInsecureConnection = false, enableTlsHostnameVerification = false

ERROR org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.PulsarWorkerService - Error Starting up in worker

pulsar[14602]: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.PulsarAdminException$GettingAuthenticationDataException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.PulsarAdminException$GettingAuthenticationDataException: org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException$AuthenticationException: Unable to obtain an access token: Unauthorized (access_denied)
```

The settings in my broker.conf are as follows:

```
authenticationProviders=org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.oidc.AuthenticationProviderOpenID
openIDAllowedTokenIssuers=https://login.someweb.com/
openIDAllowedAudiences=https://auth0.someweb.com/maas, https://stg.dev.auth0.com/userinfo
openIDRoleClaim=https://wrrek.com/role
....
brokerClientAuthenticationPlugin=org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.auth.oauth2.AuthenticationOAuth2
brokerClientAuthenticationParameters={"privateKey":"file:///credentials/credentials_file.json","audience":"https://auth0.someweb.com/api/v2/","issuerUrl":"https://login.someweb.com/"}
```

My credentials_file.json has the following structure:

```
{
    "type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "some.id@someweb.com",
    "client_secret": "somesecret",
    "issuer_url": "https://login.someweb.com/"
}
```

When I run the curl command with the same credentials of some.id@someweb.com:somesecret on the broker server I'm able to retrieve the access token.

Am I missing some config value in pulsar, that sets the Authorisation header to Authorization: Basic base64(username:password) when making the request?

**EDIT:**

I believe my issue is actually related to the token endpoint url being presented in the "https://login.someweb.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" documentation. Annoyingly this will take a while to update to the correct url. Is there anyway in Pulsar that I can override this with the correct url?

Comment: I believe my issue may actually be with whats being shown on the ".well-known/openid-configuration" endpoint. The token_endpoint seems incorrect. Will update here once I have an answer.